# reachabilityWithHostName is not working

Tags: ios, xcode, url, reachability

I want to confirm that an URL is accessible/reachable before calling it. I knew `reachabilityWithHostName` method can help me to do this task. I used the following code to know about URL reachability. But it does not works.

```
Reachability *connection = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"stackoverflow.com"];

[connection startNotifier];

NetworkStatus netStatus = [connection currentReachabilityStatus];
```

The `netStatus` always returns `NotReachable`(means `0`) value even everything is fine.

**Notes:**

- I don't want to use any other third party reachability classes
- I downloaded the current `Reachability` class from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)
- I placed the above lines of code in my sample project's `viewDidLoad` method
- The last strange thing that I wonder is, If I set a breakpoint in the first line and run the code step by step by tapping [step over](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16906822/1389515) button in Xcode, the `netStatus`  returns correct value ?!?!?!?!

Help needed!! Confused!!

Comment: Move code in didAppear and try prefix www your url. Try also with other address (if one site will throw out request time out every time due anti DDOS protections).

Comment: yes, prefix http and try to add / at the end

Comment: @user3344236 Already used www/http/https prefixes and tried other URL's too. Nothing works. Always throwing zero.

Comment: @Injectios http://stackoverflow.com/a/11284351/1389515 It seems we should not use http/https with host name

Comment: I DON'T remember exactly what should be done, but I remember I had the same issues, did you try to put slash at the end?

Comment: Did you move code in DidAppear ? It seems for me the view or other controller is not fully loaded, then if you set breakpoints it is working due full load of view.

Answer (score 1):

Use Reachability like here: https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability

```
    Reachability *connection = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"stackoverflow.com"];
    connection.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NetworkStatus netStatus = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];
            NSLog(@"network status: %ld", netStatus);
        });
    };
    connection.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        NetworkStatus netStatus = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];
        NSLog(@"network status: %ld", netStatus);
    };

    [connection startNotifier];
```

Comment: I want to use Apple's Reachability class only. :'(